# How can I withdraw my paper from a fake conference?

Tags: research-process, conference, disreputable-publishers

I submitted one of my research paper in a fake conference by mistake. Now I want to withdraw my paper from it, But I am facing problem in withdrawal as no email id is given on that website. The problem is that now my paper has been accepted by another conference. But according to Turnitin, my abstract is already published somewhere else. Does anyone here know how and where to report such fake conferences?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _4% matches with the abstract which I submitted earlier in that conference_. Matches with what? The other abstracts in the conference? Or something else?

Comment: Did the conference actually take place?

Comment: The abstract of my research paper is present on the website. Now each time I run a plagiarism check on  my paper it matches with the text on that conference website.

Comment: I didn't register there. According to the website it'll take place in August 2016. But as its fake so this also is a lie.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. Why does this 4% have anything to do with the conference? If I understand it right, you ran a tool like turnitin and get 4%. This means the abstract of your paper has 4% plagiarism rate which may not be a big deal if you did not plagiarize. But this 4% is your problem, not theirs unless they modified your abstract.

Comment: Yes. It's a problem for me, not them. The problem is that now my paper has been accepted by another conference. But according to Turnitin, my abstract is already published somewhere else. Now, I do believe its is a problem worth worrying? Because my current publisher may raise this case that my paper is already present somewhere else.

Comment: @scaaahu : 4% on just abstract means a lot! Because it's indicating that this part is already present somewhere..

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information you stated in the previous comments. They are critical information for your question. I believe you have at least another problem - double submission.

Comment: _The problem is that now my paper has been accepted by another conference._ -- So you submitted the same paper to two conferences? Even if one of them was fake, that was a serious mistake on your part.

Comment: @JeffE Why is submitting the same paper to two conferences a "mistake"? There's nothing immoral or unethical about presenting the same work in progress to multiple audiences.

Comment: @shane: It sounds like you're talking about proposing an oral presentation to two conferences.  JeffE is talking about submitting the same *paper* twice.  The rules for paper multiple submission are different than for talks, and they also differ among fields.  (I believe JeffE's field is CS and that conference proceedings, not journals, are the preferred method of publication.  Take whatever you know about submission to multiple journals in your field, and in his it applies to conferences.)

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, I get that this is how CS works. So, why are we thinking that OP is in CS? Most of the conferences I go to I submit a full 3000 word paper, and one reads the entire paper out loud to the audience. I've read those same 3000 words to more than one group of people. Why on earth think that is inappropriate?

Comment: @Zeb Can you please update your post with the following two bits of information: (i) Your field of study and (ii) whether either conference asked you to agree not to send your work elsewhere. The right answer to your question may depend on the answers to both.

Comment: @shane: In this question, it is clearly stated that the first, noxious, conference has already published OP's work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42928/discussion-between-shane-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: @BenVoigt The OPs question merely says that the paper has been "accepted" and that it's abstract is available online (at least, we can assume to some plagiarism detection tool like turnitin). I'd think the OP is implying that the whole paper *hasn't* been published online since he or she is only mentioning the abstract. But really we need more details from the OP about the case, so I think I have nothing more to say on the topic until we hear from OP.

Comment: @JeffE: I submitted the paper to the other conference after I came to know that the first one was fake and I was never going to publish my work in two conferences. This is why I never preceded with registration process in the first conference. And upon acceptance in the second conference, I requested the first one to remove my work which, according to them, they did but it still shows up in Google search results. But yesterday I made a legal request to Google to remove it and they are working on it.

Comment: My work is 'not' published in the fake conference. Only the submitted abstract shows up upon searching, along with my name and title of the paper.

Comment: @shane: i)The field of my work is Computer science. ii) Neither of the conferences asked me to do that. Because I requested the first one to withdraw my paper and I didn't tell the second one about it as I never preceded with any registration process with the first one.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies and answers but still, I haven't found any solution. This situation which I am facing right now might have been faced by many people but why is that no action is taken against it ever? In the second part of my question I've asked where to 'Report' such fake conferences because they are conning people on daily basis. Is there any authority/legal body to whom we can inform?

Comment: @Zeb I think in the light of the comments below, you should probably just send an email describing your problem to the program chair as soon as possible. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, sir. I respect your opinion. But I am doubtful about it... Should I take this chance when I have not done anything unethical on my part? I think by doing so I am only going to make this situation complex for me.

Answer (score 7):

The fake conference is unlikely to co-operate – it's a *fake conference* operating for unscrupulous reasons. You can try, but I wouldn't expect them to play ball.

Your best chance of success is to clearly explain the situation to the organizers real conference, and hope that they understand your situation and accept your paper / talk request without problems.

Answer (score -2):

This is a horrible situation for you. Until this moment, I never heard of "fake conferences". I just read about them, and the source I was just reading said, and I'm paraphrasing, there is very little difference between fake and legitimate conferences because they are both based on status-enhancement and profit-making rather than the spreading/seeking of knowledge. Unbelievable.

**I would report it to your administration and discuss it with them to find out if there's any official action that can be taken**. If there isn't any recourse, then I think you have found yourself a **MAJOR** career opportunity. Set up a business that clarifies which conferences are fake and which are legitimate. Sort of like an "Angie's List" of conferences.

Comment: These fake conference and journals have been around for some time. Beall maintains a list of some of them [here](https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/)

Comment: @shane Thanks for that information about the list. I guess it needs to be increased to capture all or most of them. People are still getting the shaft.

Comment: I am well aware of the situation but instead of crying about the situation I need a solution to get out of it :) Up till this point even I wasn't aware of it but there are few 'signs' by which you can get to know that a particular conference is fake.